# How does nil? work in ruby?

Tags: ruby

How come ().nil? is true in Ruby?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple answer: `()` is an empty expression that evaluates to `nil`.

More detailed: all expressions have a result in Ruby, returning `nil` if there's nothing better to return. `()` doesn't cause any action by itself, so an expression that is merely `()` has nothing in particular to return. Thus the result of the expression is set to `nil`, and so `().nil?` evaluates an empty expression, decides there's nothing much to return so returns `nil`. This is indeed equal to `nil`, so `nil?` says `true`.

Comment: Every time I think Ruby is done surprising me, it gets me again.  Who woulda thought () is a valid expression?

Comment: +1 Who knew Ruby was so laid back when it comes to evaluating expressions?

Comment: @klochner, @Jim I guess the ruby authors took the ideas of "lazy evaluation" in a slightly different way :)

Answer (score 2):

Playing in irb...

```
a = ()
a.class # => NilClass
a.nil? # => true
```